# What is access concentration?

Tags: theravada, personal-practice

When sit for the meditation ears were blocked. Just like sink into the water. But sounds were heard.  With the time it's  heard in less intensity. Is that access concentration? Before  this developed experience the momentary  nature  of the in breath and out breath. As well as the momentary nature  of consciousness along with that withe the break of the in breath and outbreath.

Comment: One of the defining attributes of access concentration is dissociation with thoughts. Thoughts may be there, but one is not caught inside them.

Comment: While  walking  suddenly thought disappear and noticed of foot steps appeared . After that sitting  meditation thoughts disappear. Thoughts removed and cool and peacefulness of mind appear.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're making great progress! :-)

Comment: Thank you. Is it permanent?

Comment: Remember the entire of this clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOqZ43MKSqg and  https://medium.com/capoeirawellness/instructions-on-anapanasati-meditation-for-beginners-38db38787fe3 Then you will understand the only way is getting mind's focus back to breath in and out. Don't be bored, don't desire to the resultant, just be happy and relax to watch on breath.

Comment: Is it permanent? I try not to answer questions like that, because they arise from longing. At best, one might say there is an abiding that knows no time or causality.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the surefire way is to consult a qualified meditation teacher. For the mean time, you could read more about access concentraion from Ven. Bodhi's ["Eightfold Noble Path"](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/waytoend.html):

> When the learning sign appears, the meditator leaves off the preliminary sign and fixes his attention on the new object. In due time still another object will emerge out of the learning sign. This object, called the "counterpart sign" (patibhaga-nimitta), is a purified mental image many times brighter and clearer than the learning sign. The learning sign is compared to the moon seen behind a cloud, the counterpart sign to the moon freed from the cloud. Simultaneously with the appearance of the counterpart sign, the five absorption factors suppress the five hindrances, and the mind enters the stage of concentration called upacara-samadhi, "access concentration." Here, in access concentration, the mind is drawing close to absorption. It has entered the "neighbourhood" (a possible meaning of upacara) of absorption, but more work is still needed for it to become fully immersed in the object, the defining mark of absorption.

> With further practice the factors of concentration gain in strength and bring the mind to absorption (appana-samadhi). Like access concentration, absorption takes the counterpart sign as object. The two stages of concentration are differentiated neither by the absence of the hindrances nor by the counterpart sign as object; these are common to both. What differentiates them is the strength of the jhana factors. In access concentration the jhana factors are present, but they lack strength and steadiness. Thus the mind in this stage is compared to a child who has just learned to walk: he takes a few steps, falls down, gets up, walks some more, and again falls down. But the mind in absorption is like a man who wants to walk: he just gets up and walks straight ahead without hesitation.

Answer (score 0):

Pāmojja, joy out of letting go, surrender (Saddha, Sila), is what marks the entrance of the path.